# ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask(), not sure did i get it correct?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, subnet

I know there is no entry of what am doing but am sure there are pepole who are familiar with `ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask()`.

After i call `ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask()` to convert `OnLinkPrefixLength` to get subnet mask.

`ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask()` gives me some weird number "16777215".

This is part that am not sure did i got it right, the weird number "16777215" is ULONG representation of network part, when i convert it to bits it gives me "111111111111111111111111", then i split it in parts of 8 bits and the result i get is "255 255 255"

Small part of code:

```
PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = NULL;
PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pUnicast = NULL;
ULONG subnet = 0;
PULONG mask = &subnet;
pUnicast = pCurrAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress;

if (pUnicast != NULL)
{
    for (i = 0; pUnicast != NULL; i++)
    {   
        struct sockaddr_in  *sockaddr_ipv4;
        sockaddr_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr;
        printf("IPv4 pUnicast %s \n", inet_ntoa(sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr));

        ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask(pUnicast->OnLinkPrefixLength, mask);

        pUnicast = pUnicast->Next;
    }
}
```

Ok, my question is did i get it right?

If no?
Any hint would be great?

Thank you :)

Comment: That value is equal to `0x00ffffff` which seems like a fine mask to me. Can you please elaborate on your problem? And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My problem is, is that good way to transform that "weird number" to mask?

Comment: @Genato It is already a mask. I think what you are really asking for is to convert the mask to a *human readable string* in dotted format, like "255.255.255.0", is that right? There are several functions that can do that - `inet_ntoa()`, `inet_ntop()`, `RtlIpv4AddressToString()`, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nice, i've been busting my head with some crazy functions how to transform that weird number into human readable string... `inet_ntop()` works great.. thx  :) +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for beginners

you can use the function

```
union { ULONG ul; BYTE b[4]; } m; 
ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask(netmask_length, &m.ul);
```

Next:

```
yourString.Format(L"%u.%u.%u.%u", m.b[0], m.b[1], m.b[2], m.b[3]);
```

yourString = 255.255.255.255